# Margin to the scrollbar only (not to recyclerview) on recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollbar

My recycler view lies under my toolbar, as you can see from the first picture. However, I have a scrollbar on the right side of it. I have to give a margin-top to this scrollbar. I have tried with giving style. And I know about clip padding with padding-top and padding-bottom, however, I need this exactly. Are there any ways to make it real?

[This is my problem](https://ibb.co/txqZm4Y)

[The result that I want](https://ibb.co/LhCNyjb)

P.S. I know that it is not the best practice. I would appreciate any help. It is one of my first questions, don't judge me so strong. :)

**My main XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="?attr/background1"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
tools:context=".ui.main.HomeActivity">

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pager" />

<include layout="@layout/toolbar_sura_detail" />

<include layout="@layout/player" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**My Fragment XML inside ViewPager**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="?attr/background1">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/kuranDetailList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scrollbarSize="2dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/thumbforrecycle"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your recyclerView and see if it helps

Comment: If not I suggest you upload your `xml` file

Comment: Thank you, for your response. I have added as you said, but nothing changed. Ok I am uploading my XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this structure in your main XML and add scrolling layout behaviour for ViewPager

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout...
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout...
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar...

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/pager"
  app:layout_behavior = "com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have accepted your answer, but I have only one reputation. So wait until I earn fifteen ))

Comment: @prsnlme You are welcome I am also new at stackoverflow.com :)